# HTML/PHP Site Isn't Displaying Table Correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

After setting up an Apache web server on my local machine, I've attempted to use a php document to handle uploads/downloads from the server. I used the tutorial found at:

[PHP Upload/Download Tutorial](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2016/09/file-upload-view-and-download-php-mysql.html)

It accepts uploads as normal (after fixing a flaw with page navigation on line 21 of the index.php page ["upload.php" should be "uploads.php"]), but it doesn't display the table of uploaded files as it should. I've attached the index.php code in case something obvious stands out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload View & Download file in PHP and MySQL | Demo</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 well">
        <form action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <legend>Select File to Upload:</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="file1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info"/>
            </div>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['st'])) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                <?php if ($_GET['st'] == 'success') {
                        echo "File Uploaded Successfully!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Invalid File Extension!';
                    } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>View</th>
                        <th>Download</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $i = 1;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" target="_blank">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" download>Download</td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note: I do have the bootstrap.css files downloaded so it's not some weird visual thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you sure you have entries in you database?

Comment: There has to be more code than that.  How do you obtain $result?  I see no query, no database connection, ...  Then your form is `method="post"` but you check $_GET ?